# Unable to update anything; GPG error

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, 13.04, gnupg

This is the first time I've ever posted to a forum, so bear with me. Might I add I'm also new to Ubuntu. So far, it's stressful. But I haven't given up. Ok I'm running 13.04 and would like to upgrade, but can't seem to get update manager to work. When I run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get this back

```
Get:1 http ://extras.ubuntu. com raring Release.gpg
Get:2 http ://extras.ubuntu. com raring Release
Ign http ://extras.ubuntu. com raring Release
E: GPG error: http ://extras.ubuntu. com raring 
Release: The following signatures
were invalid NODATA 1 NODATA 2
```

I promise you I've tried everything under the sun and googled myself to death the past several days trying to figure this out. If you need more info please tell me, sorry I'm not sure what else to say....help?! :(

Comment: Not an expert, but I think 13.04 is so old that there is no upgrade path any more.  Back up your data and do a clean install.